# Django error: needs to have a value for field "..." before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

When saving a form I am getting this error:
"" needs to have a value for field "surveythread" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Models.py:

```
class SurveyResult(models.Model):
    stay = models.OneToOneField(Stay, related_name='survey')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vote_service = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def getThreads(self):
        return SurveyThread.objects.filter(parent_survey = self)

    threads = property(getThreads)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.vote and 'Good' or 'Bad'

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = '-created'

class SurveyThread(models.Model):
    survey = models.ManyToManyField(SurveyResult, related_name='parent_survey')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
survey_list = SurveyResult.objects.filter(stay__guest__user=request.user) \
                                      .select_related('stay', 'stay__guest')

forms = {}
for survey in survey_list:
  forms[survey] = SurveyThreadForm(data=request.POST or None, survey=survey)

  if forms[survey].is_valid():
    instance = forms[survey].save()
    return redirect('.')
```

forms.py

```
class SurveyThreadForm(forms.Form):

    comment = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.survey = kwargs.pop('survey', None)

        if not self.survey:
            raise NotImplementedError("SurveyResult object is required at this moment")

        super(SurveyThreadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['comment'].label = "Message to send to guest:"

    def save(self, commit=True):
        s = SurveyThread()
        s.survey = self.survey
        s.email = "test@test.com"
        s.comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']

        if commit:
            s.save()
        return s
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError at /
"<SurveyThread: SurveyThread object>" needs to have a value for field "surveythread" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
"<SurveyThread: SurveyThread object>" needs to have a value for field "surveythread" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
Exception Location: /Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __init__, line 586
Python Executable:  /Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/tlovett1/guestretain',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Sun, 7 Jul 2013 10:22:55 -0500
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/guestretain/retain/apps/profiles/utils.py in _wrapped_view
                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/endless_pagination/decorators.py in decorated
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/guestretain/retain/apps/dashboard/views.py in dashboard
            instance = forms[survey].save() ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/guestretain/retain/apps/surveys/forms.py in save
        s.survey = self.survey ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__
        manager = self.__get__(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __get__
            through=self.field.rel.through, ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/tlovett1/.virtualenvs/guestretain/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __init__
                                 (instance, source_field_name)) ...
▶ Local vars
```

I'm new to Django and Python. I can post the debug trace or migration file if needed, but I have a feeling it's a simple fix. Obviously the point is I want to save multiple survey thread for each survey result.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the exact error message and traceback would be very useful for us to give you and answer.

Comment: I added the full error message and traceback to the original thread.

Answer (score 43):

Ok, the code is slightly messy, I'm sure you'll be better off [tackling your problem with `ModelForms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). Seems to me the problem actually is the line:

```
s.survey = self.survey
```

because `s` object hasn't been written to the database yet, so accessing it's `survey` ManyToMany field can yield problems. If you want to copy the same set of surveys from `self`  to `s` you should do it iterating over them like this:

If this yields the same error, then try to do `s.save()` first and later copy the items:

```
s.save()
for item in self.survey:
    s.survey.add(item)
```

Your code is likely to remain like this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    s = SurveyThread()
    # these fields aren't problematic
    s.email = "test@test.com"
    s.comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']
    # you can add s.save() here to remove problems associated with object 
    # not yet persisted
    # s.save()
    for item in self.survey:
        s.survey.add(item)
    if commit:
        s.save()
    return s
```

I can see you have a `if commit:` to persist the object, so try to accommodate the code to make use of it. If the first version of my answer worked then you'll be fine with the `s.save()` at the end, if the second is the one who worked, then you'll have to adjust the code a little to stick to the `commit` value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've the similar problem as well. Your hint made my day! The error message is so confusing to me... `"<SurveyThread: SurveyThread object>" needs to have a value for field "surveythread" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.` The field `surveythread` actually means a field in table `parent_survey`.

Answer (score 4):

In this part of the code in `forms.py`, you're setting the `survey` field on the `SurveyThread` object to `None`, yet it's not allowed to be `None` according to your `models.py`:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    s = SurveyThread()
    s.survey = None     ### This is the problem
    s.email = "test@test.com"
    s.comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']

    if commit:
        s.save()
    return s
```

You have to set `survey` to a `SurveyResult` object before you can save it, or allow it to be `None` in the model.

I think you want to change it to say:

```
s.survey = self.survey
```

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry. I am getting the error still with s.survey = self.survey. I changed it to None while I was debugging and forgot to change it back. I updated my original post to reflect this.