# <XXX> needs to have a value for field xxx before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

I currently have the following 3 models

```
class modelToolName(models.Model):
    tool_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)

class modelBodyPart(models.Model):
    part_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)

class modelNormalBodyPartResult(models.Model):
    body_part = models.ForeignKey(modelBodyPart, default=None)
    tool_name = models.ManyToManyField(modelToolName, default=None, blank=True)
    result = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I am attempting to insert value into the `modelNormalBodyPartResult` in this way

```
result="xxxx"
bodpart = modelBodyPart.objects.get(part_name="xxx") #--->returns object fine
toolqset = modelToolName.objects.get(tool_name="xxx")#--->returns object fine
modelNormalBodyPartResult.objects.create(body_part=bodpart,tool_name = toolqset,result=result) --->error
```

and I get the error

```
<modelNormalBodyPartResult: modelNormalBodyPartResult object> needs to have a value for field "modelnormalbodypartresult" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505935/django-error-needs-to-have-a-value-for-field-before-this-many-to-many-rel)  post but still could not figure out the issue any suggestions in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: did you defined new obj of modelNormalBodyPartResult While inserting value ?

Comment: no I always create a new object like this modelobject.objects.create(...)

Comment: Are you sure you want a many-to-many there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes the reason is because an instance of `modelToolName` can be associated with multiple `modelNormalBodyPartResult` and at the same time `modelNormalBodyPartResult` can have multiple entries associated with a `modelToolName` instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object first, then add the `ManyToMany` related objects to it,

```
result="xxxx"
bodpart = modelBodyPart.objects.get(part_name="xxx")
toolqset = modelToolName.objects.get(tool_name="xxx")
item = modelNormalBodyPartResult.objects.create(body_part=bodpart,result=result)
item.tool_name.add(toolqset)
item.save()
```